# Error with creating Entity from database in NetBeans

Tags: mysql, database, netbeans, entity, driver

I have a problem when creating Entity Classes from Database in NetBeans. When I try to do it I get the following message:

> The name of the driver class for the datasource is missing

I can't understand what I'm missing when creating connection to mysql database. Where I miss set name for driver classes?

Comment: show your code. We can't see where something is missing if we can't see the lines it might be missing from. Edit the question to include your creation of the connection

Comment: I don't have a code at this moment. 
I create new connection in NetBeans
Tab Services > Databases > New Connection 
in open window select MySQL (Connector/ J driver) >
set parameters for connection to mysql database(database name, password etc) Next > Next > Finish
After that try create Entity from database and got error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem with creating for java ee application. In java se work well. In java ee need work with DataSource.

Answer (score -2):

check your datasource configuration from your datasource aplication server ..

Comment: Could you explain what the questioner is meant to check?